# Android Compose: How to display HTML text with image tag inside text?

Tags: android, html, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a string that comes from an API that contains HTML formatted text, that I need to display to the user using Compose. For simple text with formatting it's pretty easy, using this function:

```
@Composable
fun HtmlText(
    html: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context -> TextView(context) },
        update = { it.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT) }
    )
}
```

However, the HTML string also contains an `img` tag with link to the image I need to load and display in the middle of the text. Retrieving link is simple and I assume I could use Coil or Glide to load the image itself, however, I have no idea how to display it correctly, especially since it also has additional parameters for `width` and `height`. Example of the HTML text:

```
<p>\nThis is a paragraph with image (external src)\n
<img src=\"https://www.example.com/_next/image?url=some_image.png" width=\"380\" height=\"200\">
\n</p>\n
<p style=\"color: black; text-align: justify;\">Some more text as an example</p>"
```

I will be really grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can make it by provide an `Html.ImageGetter` to `HtmlCompat.fromHtml`.

Here is an example that we have made.

First, Make a Custom Image Getter. I use Coil for this example.

```kotlin
class CoilImageGetter(
    private val textView: TextView,
    private val imageLoader: ImageLoader = Coil.imageLoader(textView.context),
    private val sourceModifier: ((source: String) -> String)? = null,
    private val fixedImageWidth: Int,
) : Html.ImageGetter {

    override fun getDrawable(source: String): Drawable {
        val finalSource = sourceModifier?.invoke(source) ?: source
        val placeholder = ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY).toBitmap(100, 100)
        val drawablePlaceholder = DrawablePlaceHolder(textView.resources, placeholder)
        imageLoader.enqueue(
            ImageRequest.Builder(textView.context).data(finalSource).apply {
                target { drawable ->
                    drawablePlaceholder.updateDrawable(fixedImageWidth, drawable)
                    // invalidating the drawable doesn't seem to be enough...
                    textView.text = textView.text
                }
                scale(Scale.FIT)
            }.build()
        )
        // Since this loads async, we return a "blank" drawable, which we update later
        return drawablePlaceholder
    }

    private class DrawablePlaceHolder(
        resource: Resources,
        bitmap: Bitmap,
    ) : BitmapDrawable(resource, bitmap) {

        private var drawable: Drawable? = null

        override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
            drawable?.draw(canvas)
        }

        fun updateDrawable(width: Int, drawable: Drawable) {
            this.drawable = drawable
            val aspectRatio = drawable.intrinsicHeight.toFloat() / drawable.intrinsicWidth.toFloat()
            val height = (width.toFloat() * aspectRatio).toInt()
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height)
            setBounds(0, 0, width, height)
        }
    }
}
```

Then for Html composable component

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HtmlText(
    html: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    htmlFlags: Int = FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY,
    htmlTagHandler: TagHandler = ListTagHandler(),
    imageSourceModifier: ((source: String) -> String)? = null,
    @ColorRes color: Int,
    @StyleRes style: Int,
    typeface: Typeface? = null,
    onClicked: ((String) -> Unit)? = null
) {
    // This is used to determine the bounds of Drawable inside htmlText
    // which is handling by CoilImageGetter.
    var componentWidth by remember {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }

    val text = remember(html) {
        if (htmlTagHandler is ListTagHandler) {
            ListTagHandler.changeListTag(html)
        } else {
            html
        }
    }

    AndroidView(
        factory = {
            AppCompatTextView(it)
        },
        modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
            componentWidth = it.size.width
        }.testTag("html-text"),
        update = { textView ->
            textView.text = text.parseAsHtml(
                htmlFlags,
                tagHandler = htmlTagHandler,
                imageGetter = CoilImageGetter(
                    textView,
                    sourceModifier = imageSourceModifier,
                    fixedImageWidth = componentWidth
                )
            )

            textView.gravity = Gravity.START
            textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(textView.context, color))
            TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(textView, style)
            textView.setLinkTextColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(textView.context, Color.BLUE)
            )
            textView.typeface = typeface
            textView.handleUrlClicks(onClicked)
        },
    )
}

private fun AppCompatTextView.handleUrlClicks(onClicked: ((String) -> Unit)? = null) {
    linksClickable = true
    text = SpannableStringBuilder.valueOf(text).apply {
        getSpans(0, length, URLSpan::class.java).forEach {
            setSpan(
                object : ClickableSpan() {
                    override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                        onClicked?.invoke(it.url.trim())
                    }
                },
                getSpanStart(it),
                getSpanEnd(it),
                Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            )
            removeSpan(it)
        }
    }
    movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).